# How to code an annotation inside an annotation in a class?

Tags: java, annotations

I'm trying to code, for fun, a class that use an annotion with another annotation inside, but I don't understand how to code.

## My code

### First annotation

```
@interface FirstAnnotation {
    String author();
}
```

### Second annotation, contains the first annotation

```
public @interface SecondAnnotation {
    FirstAnnotation inside();
    int version();
}
```

### Class with annotation

```
@FirstAnnotation(
    author = "alessandro"
)
@SecondAnnotation(
    version = 1,
    inside = /*Compilation code: what code? FirstAnnotation, this??*/   
)
public class GeneralClass {

    /*
     * a generic method
     */ 
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("method");
    }

}
```

What I have to put in row with string **Compilation code**, as reference to actual value of ***FirstAnnotation*** in the class?

Comment: @FirstAnnotation(author = "something")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You class should be:

```
@SecondAnnotation(
    version = 1,
    inside = @FirstAnnotation(
          author = "alessandro"
    )   
)
public class GeneralClass {

    /*
     * a generic method
     */ 
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("method");
    }

}
```